# Calling id selector from another selector

Tags: objective-c

I have a selector declared with id sender, like this:

```
- (void)fbLoginClicked:(id)sender
{ }
```

I want to call it from another method like this:

```
[self fbLoginClicked];
```

But,I'm getting this error:

> No visible selector 'fbLoginClicked'

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method signature requires that you pass a parameter (sender) to the method.

I'm assuming that this method is also an IBAction, hence why it requires a sender parameter.

To call this method through code you need to pass it a parameter, assuming that parameter is not used then you can simply call:

`[self fbLoginClicked:nil];`

If this method is not an IBAction and nothing is done with the `sender` parameter, then you could change the method signature to:

`- (void)fbLoginClicked`